# How to auto restart a service when killed?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I have already red many posts about the subject, some of these works, but only on some devices. For example it works on my Nexus 4, Nexus 5 with cyaogenmod, but not on my Xiaomi Mi2s (jelly beam 4.1.1)

I tried setting it sticky, using alarm, and broadcast receiver on destroy. But neither of them worked out. When I kill the application it never wake up again. But on the same device Whatsapp works perfectly, and even if I kill it, it wake up again..

Is there any way to do it without use GCM?

Some of the link I already looked up:

[How to restart a killed service automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666192/how-to-restart-a-killed-service-automatically)

[Service that repeatedly runs a method, after an amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616912/services-that-runs-a-methode-after-an-amount-of-time/19617008#19617008)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21551045/627307

Comment: you could have an alarmmanager every few minutes to restart your service if required. also have you tried to see if any `onStop` or `onDestroyed` methods are called?

Comment: START_STICKY not working?

Comment: onDestroyed is not called, and start sticky neither on Xiaomi. Instead whatsapp service is not killed

Comment: Did you find any solution for your query? I face same issue with Xiaomi devices.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if it will solve the issue for you or not but it worked for me.

I'm running MIUI 6.6.10

1. Open the **Security** app provided by Xiaomi
2. Click on permissions -> Autostart
3. Here allow your app to auto start

WhatsApp and all famous apps work because Xiaomi white listed them and allowed them to autostart.

Comment: did you check whether it's restarting the service or not ? if yes, how did you check ? because I have enabled the Autostart option for my app, still don't know how find whether it is restarted on killing it or not.