# How to keep background service alive when I clear the RAM - Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-service

I have made a background service in my project. How can I keep the background service alive?

I use the following code:

```
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            ambil_jam();
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }
```

However, it only keeps it alive when I close the app and when I try to clear the RAM the background service closed.

I also use this:

```
[Register("onTaskRemoved", "(Landroid/content/Intent;)V", "GetOnTaskRemoved_Landroid_content_Intent_Handler")]
public virtual void OnTaskRemoved()
{
     StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(SimpleService)));
}
```

However, it is never called when I close my app. Does the method `onTaskRemoved()` override, or do I need to call it again?

I'm using Xamarin.Android.

Comment: what do you mean by "clear the RAM". Please explain exactly what you are doing.

Comment: sorry, i mean close the app using task manager

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: I'm using Xiaomi redmi note 2 prime, Android version 5.0.2

Comment: Is your `Service` being automatically restarted after it is killed? Add logging to `onCreate()` in your `Service` so you can check.

Comment: Are you swiping the task from the list, or are you using the Settings->Applications->MyApp and then "force close"?

Comment: yup, i'm swiping the task from the list. I try on facebook and twitter, but the services turn on again

Comment: is your `Service` being automatically restarted?

Comment: no, i'm just using StartCommandResult.Sticky, do you have an example how to  create Service that can automatically restarted?

Comment: There are power-saving controls on some of these phones that may be preventing your `Service` from getting restarted. Please see this question and the answer.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615633/how-to-auto-restart-a-service-when-killed and let me know if this helped you.

Comment: Because i only have xiaomi smartphone to develop my app, then follow the instruction `Open the Security app provided by Xiaomi, Click on permissions -> Autostart, Here allow your app to auto start`. It works perfectly now!!! Thanks @DavidWasser :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are power-saving controls on some phones that may be precenting your `Service` from getting restarted. Xiaomi, Huawei, LG and others have a separate setting that allows you to control this.

- Open the Security app provided by Xiaomi
- Click on permissions -> Autostart
- Here allow your app to auto start